# Date/Time Conversion Failure in VBA using SQL Database Query

Tags: mysql, sql, excel, vba, datetime-format

First thing's first. Here's my code.

```
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rec1 As ADODB.Recordset
Dim connStr As String
Dim thisSql As String
Dim testStr As String


Sub Button3_Click()
Worksheets("Sheet5").Range("N1") = Worksheets("Sheet5").Range("N1") + 1

Set conn = New ADODB.Connection

connStr = "DSN=myDatabase;UID=myUsername;PWD=myPassword;APP=Microsoft Office 2013;WSID=myPCname;DATABASE=myDatabase"

conn.Open connStr

thisSql = "SELECT myDatabase.OrderNumber, myDatabase.CustomerName, myDatabase.ShipProd, myDatabase.Sum of Sales, myDatabase.InvoiceDate FROM myDatabaseAddress "
thisSql = thisSql & "WHERE (myDatabase.ShipProd Like '" & Worksheets("Sheet5").Range("C2") & "') "
thisSql = thisSql & "GROUP BY myDatabase.CustomerName, myDatabase.OrderNumber, myDatabase.InvoiceDate, myDatabase.ShipProd, myDatabase.OEELPrimarySlsCrdtWhse "
thisSql = thisSql & "HAVING (myDatabase.OEELPrimarySlsCrdtWhse Like 'MI%') "
thisSql = thisSql & "AND (myDatabase.InvoiceDate Between {ts '" & Worksheets("Sheet5").Range("E2") & "'} And {ts '" & Worksheets("Sheet5").Range("F2") & "'}) "
thisSql = thisSql & "ORDER BY myDatabase.CustomerName ASC"


Set rec1 = New ADODB.Recordset
rec1.Open thisSql, conn

Worksheets("Sheet5").Range("A3:F10000").Clear

With Worksheets("Sheet5").QueryTables.Add(Connection:=rec1, Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet5").Range("A3"))
    .Name = "data"
    .FieldNames = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With

End Sub
```

I am trying to send a query with parameters and bring back some results from my SQL database. One of the parameters that I want to pass is a date range that InvoiceDate must fall between. These dates are located in cells E2 and F2. When I run the code, I receive an error that says

```
Run-time error '-2147217913 (80040e07)':

[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

When I push "Debug" on the message box, it highlights the line with the code

```
rec1.Open thisSql, conn
```

I have tried formatting the cells in the spreadsheet many different ways including yyyymmdd and m/d/yyyy h:mm and mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.

Another problem that I'm running into is that one of the field names is "Sum of Sales". This section generates an error saying that "of" is a reserved keyword.

If there are any suggestions that anyone has, that would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE

I managed to fix the date/time error by changing

```
thisSql = thisSql & "AND (myDatabase.InvoiceDate Between {ts '" & Worksheets("Sheet5").Range("E2") & "'} And {ts '" & Worksheets("Sheet5").Range("F2") & "'}) "
```

to

```
thisSql = thisSql & "AND (myDatabase.InvoiceDate Between '" & Worksheets("Sheet5").Range("E2") & "' And '" & Worksheets("Sheet5").Range("F2") & "') "
```

Although, I am still working on fixing the field name problem. I have tried putting 'myDatabase.Sum of Sales' in single quotes like it is here, but that just returns "myDatabase.Sum of Sales" in all of the cells in the corresponding column.

Comment: You can fix "Sum of Sales" by putting it inside square brackets like this myDatabase.[Sum of Sales]